# How to push element into typed array in an object

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error with this code

```
Argument of type 'Dogs | Cats | Fishs' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dogs & Cats & Fishs'.
  Type 'Dogs' is not assignable to type 'Dogs & Cats & Fishs'.
    Property 'owner' is missing in type 'Dogs' but required in type 'Cats'.
```

```
interface Dogs {
    height: number,
    age: number,
    race: string,
    available: boolean,
}

interface Cats {
    height: number,
    age: number,
    owner: string
}

interface Fishs {
    weight: number,
    age: number,
    water: "sweet" | "salty"
}

interface Foo {
    animals: {
        dogs?: Dogs[],
        cats?: Cats[],
        fishs?: Fishs[] 
    }
}


type FooKeys = keyof Foo["animals"]
type FooState = Required<Foo>["animals"]
type FooStateTypes = Required<FooState>[keyof FooState][0]


const addAnimal = (fooState: FooState, animal: FooStateTypes, fooKey: keyof FooState) => {
    const fooStateAnimal = fooState[fooKey]
    if(fooStateAnimal) {
        fooStateAnimal.push(animal)
    } else {
        fooState[fooKey] = [animal]
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmBnZBvAWAChlTkALCYTcsALmRAFcBbAI2gBpizk5MIDZuy48yURIOTYwUUJm4kycAG5xgAGzhsNUtunS64IRQF9ixUJFiTkAYThhchJaUrVaQ1hyiLe-KWEfPzJ0AHcQaAYZORBMYnMiS3BoeCRkADFgbHJnMVIwqhp6Rm9RVz4BLxFffOQwxyjkACJsQogwZuQAHxbsOA0wAE9mhIsiK1TbDIN8OuNgFgHsBhdeXgATLGwAfgYMHABtAF0Q9eQER12GBycTs-WYbNy9zOfsE%20Q6xMTx4YAHFAzdAAaQgQ1wAF5kABrcHoGCZAyHZoLJYabDNY7EAFAgwAZTAjWQ0IAShAAI5MYBQCAbAA8wIAfCi0cssTihoCkehCY0ACpciBQ5Dkqk0umMglEyAsuFDBE8vmQY6HAAM2KSWoQ6BAMj4Gw2AEEQIsBiTkAAKGDSxoMYHKiCcPim9H222QQWA7DOm2g8EMeWKh0yiAAShJTLmFR1erAyD9jpNZo0FsTocOfrBQ01vGAMGtHogyfREbW5wTRZLAwAdP8mDlLWyNGHvsgIBiUOXzunGpmDNnjhbDs3c2QfkA)

I guess that is because the compiler cannot assure that the `animal` I am trying to `.push()` into `fooStateAnimal` or try to assign to `fooState[fooKey]` is of the the proper type. However, I do not know how to tell the compiler that it is of the correct type.

Comment: It's telling you the right thing - there's nothing to prevent e.g. `addAnimal(state, cat, "dogs")`. You need generic types to tie the specific key to the array it refers to. (Also the animal classes would conventionally have singular names, and the plural of fish is fishes.)

Comment: Once you fix the typings this runs into lack of support for correlated unions, [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the fix is to switch to generics and refactor as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wEpnOW) for your use case.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this solves it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jcalz It would be nice if you could explain your answer. I (and probably others not as familiar with TS as you) have trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NB: I'm redefining your types slightly to use more conventional naming (e.g., `Dog` for a single object, not `Dogs`; the English plural of "fish" is just "fish", or possibly "fishes" but that usually refers to multiple *species*; `Animals` instead of `FooState`, etc). If you don't mind I might go back and edit your question to use these conventions too, and then remove this section here:

```
interface Dog { height: number, age: number, race: string, available: boolean }
interface Cat { height: number, age: number, owner: string }
interface Fish { weight: number, age: number, water: "freshwater" | "saltwater"
interface Animals { dogs?: Dog[], cats?: Cat[], fish?: Fish[] }
interface Foo { animals: Animals }
type AnimalTypes = Required<Animals>[keyof Animals][number]
const addAnimal = (animals: Animals, animal: AnimalTypes, fooKey: keyof Animals) => {⋯}
```

---

The first problem is that the call signature `addAnimal()` doesn't even try to make sure that you're passing the correct `animal` type for a given `fooKey`:

```
declare const foo: Foo;
declare const cat: Cat
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "cats"); // okay
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "dogs"); // okay?!
```

So the error you're getting in the function body is reasonable.  To fix the call signature you need to *correlate* the type of `animal` and the type of `fooKey`.  This could either be done with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [tuple types for a rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types), or by making the function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of the `fooKey` parameter.  The generic version gets us closer to the full solution so let's show that:

```
type AnimalType<K extends keyof Animals> = Required<Animals>[K][number]

const addAnimal = <K extends keyof Animals>(
    animals: Animals, animal: AnimalType<K>, fooKey: K
) => {
    const animalArray = animals[fooKey]
    if (animalArray) {
        animalArray.push(animal) // error
    } else {
        animals[fooKey] = [animal] // error
    }
}

declare const foo: Foo;
declare const cat: Cat
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "cats"); // okay
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "dogs"); // error
```

Now the calls to `addAnimal()` behave more reasonably so it's harder (but not impossible) to add a `Cat` to an array of `Dog` objects.  But the function body still has essentially the same errors.  The compiler is worried that `animal` but be the wrong type to push onto `animalArray`, or that `[animal]` is the wrong type to assign to `animals[fooKey]`.  It has failed to keep track of the correlation in any way.

This is essentially the issue described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581); the language doesn't really support correlations like this.  The GitHub issue is about correlated *unions*, but refactoring to generics often has the same problem. If the compiler fails to "see" the generic logic, it will fall back to widening the generic values to their [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), and if these constraints are unions then it complains.

---

One way for you to proceed is just to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), to say that you're sure you've implemented the function correctly and that the case the compiler is concerned about is either impossible or unlikely enough not to be considered:

```
    if (animalArray) {
        animalArray.push(animal as any)
    } else {
        animals[fooKey] = [animal] as any
    }
```

This essentially gives up on compiler-verified type safety and just lets you move forward.

---

If you really want to keep some semblance of type tracking, though, you can use the approach detailed in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and refactor your operations to be expressed implicitly in terms of a "base" key-value mapping type, and generic [indexes into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) that type or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  The point is to write things in such a way that the compiler can plug in the generic type parameter and see `animalArray.push(animal)` as a single generic operation and not a union of operations.

For this example the refactoring looks like this.  The base key-value mapping type is:

```
interface AnimalMap {
    dogs: Dog
    cats: Cat
    fish: Fish
}
```

And then we can write `Animals` as essentially a mapped type over `AnimalMap`.  Actually we need to give it a parameter so that an `Animals<K>` is explicitly known to be equivalent to `Pick<Animals, K>` (using the [`Pick` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)):

```
type Animals<K extends keyof AnimalMap = keyof AnimalMap> = {
    [P in K]?: AnimalMap[P][]
}
```

So `Animals` is equivalent to `Animals<keyof AnimalMap>` which is equivalent to your original type.  But here the compiler will be able to explicitly see that when `K` is generic, that `Animals<K>` is an array of `AnimalMap[K]` objects.  That's a single generic array type and not a union of array types.

Now we can write `addAnimal` like this:

```
const addAnimal = <K extends keyof AnimalMap>(
    animals: Animals<K>, animal: AnimalMap[K], fooKey: K
) => {
    const animalArray = animals[fooKey]
    if (animalArray) {
        animalArray.push(animal)
    } else {
        animals[fooKey] = [animal]
    }
}
```

This compiles without error.  Since `animals` is typed as `Animals<K>` (and any `Animals` is automatically assignable to `Animals<K>` for any `K`.  For any `T` and `K`, `T` is assignable to `Pick<T, K>`), then `animals[fooKey]` is seen to be of generic type  `AnimalMap[K][]`.  And since `animal` is of type `AnimalMap[K]`, then you will definitely be able to `push` the latter onto the former, or assign a one-element array of the latter to the former.

And the call signature still works from the call side too:

```
declare const foo: Foo;
declare const cat: Cat
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "cats"); // okay
addAnimal(foo.animals, cat, "dogs"); // error
```

Looks good.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDmyDeyAWEwm+YAXMiAK4C2ARtADTJyYQXX1PJSLvIBnMFFCZmcAG5xgAGzh0Z-OunSK4IZAF8AsAChQkWH2QBhOGFwEiJcpVoMo4th3vd0AdxDQKQkSGw6+uDQ8EjIAGLAAviW7takLlyOLM52Sczu5t7IAEQwUBDRmYY5yAA+uQJwMmDF0KWBeiBwNIUADsYAClDoChA0uHp6yCPIBiHG4SqDuqNzLCDANNUCFACCi8syAsOjgXPjRmEbSysz86MAJlgCAPwUGJgA2gC6jLsXCOZ3FGZgr+9ZhdkDAovh7hEwa8PloYWAAJ5tFAnLYAFURhWQAF5kAAlCAARyowAKlwAPCiVgA+J4Aawg8PQMGQlO2LyenAcLxhCHQICELEul1Z2OQAAp1KdtutNitxLKZDKpeikQJmDAVABpBkUemM5msgQASmxVPOwN5-Iskq2aygvHhoptKyeGvQ2vh3KBF2AzIlCrtDpNOBhwIWUsDcHhADo2lRov6pUbQ3tkBBtigQ96w+GtgJXVqGS9RU9nTIvWH9nsYZcIAg5AVkJaBW6KFN0ABuGt1hsoZsWL62P4wuBC1lit3RstqpvmZg5QcCHJGjvIAD0a+Q6FpUZHY4VE5UU4VM8H8+umCXK-Xm+3UduAEIhro9I1dM1WgIOmEAMpgWQyN0vSKAMWYwocoQoO25oXNOSp5jCVYjBBxiGjB8wXj8aBYACKYjIuEJ-Lh2ZzKC0QQpE0TQtmSHIAiSIsgqKoQGSmppgAHpAICXAIyB6kyjFSgIZo4viRIkhA5KGjSmrspy0AVqM-aCsKCqiqxHFcTxfEMgJ0linhuYrPBcpGYqglohirFUuqhbwhQmowiaWJmlmYbKWWkaOji04Fu6RaGb64qefaUbBoZcwhQ6sbxvgiZbCwvHqPCyYkam6YCJmEWjL5boesWOKlgqxZwElIDwoZtG0bW9ZwI2ymthEKhdtmNW9k2fICoOvzmHuqlSoe6DHkJzBnrki7LquG5bjuFXZqO-VbINw15qNc65Jhk03mm9roFAz6vs+KHHAqACycBtOhmEPFgPLfD1YAwmR+BtmCh0vro9HIieGkQJxEDcbx-EGmdF2isDFnVOdbQiehTydGMGiyRCrLQ-D7Jem+x1QdMbk5SeJnbO9z4efuUrqWxf1aUDukg1K0NUgZ80E5D2zWfKUqE2jsm2f59nII5ujOa5PKddaAahd5Zn5nlAXZkF8XVF54VpSMUVRjFCZlqlcyaGmGboZFJ5+flJZlopIyBG+bV1X2YsgiobbNXoNv1fb3WmL1ugLeOk7TmtYDzhN17TXec0+wefsngH543Ft03QD0+26EAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed answere!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isCat(item: FooStateTypes):item is Cats {
    return (item as Cats).owner !== undefined;
}
function isDog(item: FooStateTypes):item is Dogs {
    return (item as Dogs).race !== undefined;
}

const addAnimal = (fooState: FooState, animal: FooStateTypes) => {    
    if(isCat(animal)) {
        fooState.cats?.push(animal)
    } else if(isDog(animal)) {
        fooState.dogs?.push(animal)
    } else {
        fooState.fishs?.push(animal)
    }
}
```

You could try this. This works as long as each type has differentiable attribute.